# Why doesn't my hard drive show up as a block device?

Tags: debian, hard-disk, storage

My external hard drives shows up on another machine, running Arch Linux, although on Debian 11 the device doesn't show up in `fdisk` or `lsblk`:

```bash
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 119.4G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 119.1G  0 part /

$ sudo fdisk -l
### /dev/ram* output has been removed.
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 119.38 GiB, 128177930240 bytes, 250347520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8e94f125

Device         Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192    532479    524288   256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      532480 250347519 249815040 119.1G 83 Linux
```

The USB hubs show up in `lsbusb`:

```bash
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Finally, `dmesg` has an I/O error:

```bash
$ dmesg | tail
[  358.698270] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 0d 06 37 90 00 00 01 00
[  358.698274] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 218511248 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  358.698328] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=5s
[  358.698337] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 0d 06 37 91 00 00 1d 00
[  358.698342] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 218511249 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 29 prio class 0
[  358.698376] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 218511250 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80000 phys_seg 28 prio class 0
[  358.698432] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 218511248 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  358.721185] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  358.960749] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  358.961333] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN Can't disable streams for endpoint 0x81, streams are being disabled already
```

It worked fine before, although I switched to btrfs, and afterwards it has stopped appearing. Additionally:

- Both on the Debian and Arch Linux machines I'm using a SATA to USB adapter.
- Both drives are 500 GB drives (that have worked fine with the adapter in the past).

How could I get my drives to appear Any help or suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the drive still works in the Arch system using the same SATA-to-USB adapter, it is possible the hardware of the Debian system simply cannot supply enough power for the HDD to run without errors.

The error messages in `dmesg` output are block-level errors: the choice of a file system type should not make a difference at that level (unless, theoretically, one filesystem type requires the drive to make much more read/write head movements than the other, and so cause the disk to consume more power - but that would also make that filesystem type perform poorly on HDDs).

You might try introducing a USB hub that has its own power supply between the Debian system and the drive. That might allow the drive to draw more power from the hub's supply instead of relying on what the Debian system can provide on its own.

If the drive previously worked with both systems and now works with neither of them, it is possible that the external drive is worn out or suffered some physical damage: external HDDs are easily damaged if e.g. the bag they're in gets dropped, or the external HDD gets knocked against a hard object.

It is also possible that previously the drive got just barely enough power from the Debian system, and as time went on, mechanical wear of the bearings caused the drive to need ever-so-slightly more power... but the Debian system just cannot supply any more.

Comment: Hello! I suppose I'll try using a USB hub for when I'm using them on the Debian system, instead of connecting them directly to the device and see if that works instead. Thank you for the advice!